# Building visage fails with "No supported regular expression match"

Tags: ubuntu, ant, build, visage

When building `visage` from source using `ant-1.7` on `ubuntu` it fails with the message

```
build.xml:52: No supported regular expression matcher found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.util.regexp.Jdk14RegexpRegexp
```

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The regular expression matcher is found in the `ant-optional` package for `Ubuntu`, and installing that solves the problem.

`sudo apt-get install ant-optional`

Answer (score 8):

FYI in Centos the package name is ant-apache-regexp

```
yum install ant-apache-regexp
```

Answer (score 0):

For suse 11 it is little bit longer

1.what is your ant exact version ? in my case it was  1.7.0

1. download the rpm : in my case the package name was ant-apache-regexp-1.7.0-200.2.noarch.rpm
2. execute the following

   rpm -i ant-apache-regexp-1.7.0-200.2.noarch.rpm